# Приложение не закрывается, остается в фоновых процессах

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Учу Windows API. Проблема заключается в том, что при закрывании приложения, оно остается в фоновых процессорах и очень сильно бьет по процессору и комп может сильно тормозить. Его можно убрать через диспетчер задачи, но это очень напрягает. Есть идеи почему так происходит и решения этой проблемы

Привожу код, может проблема в нём:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

TCHAR Class[] = L"MyClass";
TCHAR Title[] = L"Windows API";
MSG msg;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE app, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdShow, int mode)
{
    HWND window;

    int x = 1000;
    int y = 2000;

    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = Class;
    wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.hInstance = app;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Ошибка: Не зарегистрировался класс!", L"Ошибка", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

        return 0;
    }

    window = CreateWindow(
        Class,
        Title,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        x,
        y,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        app,
        NULL
    );

    if (!window)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Ошибка: Не создалось окно!", L"Ошибка", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(window);

    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if (GetMessage(&msg, window, NULL, NULL))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(NULL);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Привожу скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте ещё обработку закрытия окна

```
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    break;
```

Comment: Блин, не помогло. Я переписал код, вроде правильно. Добавил скрин

Comment: а посмотрите внимательно на свой while. мало того, что он вначале обращается к не инициализированной переменной, так ещё и пресекаете свое приложение на очень ранней стадии. В череди ещё есть события, которые не обработаны. Посмотрите внимательно на правильные примеры этого цикла http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?53